# how do i import a site given that i have [domain].sql and a folder of site files?

Tags: import

I have my own (Linux-based) in-house wp server with multisite configuration, and I need to migrate to this server from a hosting company. they have provided me with 2 things:

1. [domain].sql and
2. a [domain] folder which seems to contain all the wp files they use for currently hosting the site.

I have imported the sql file into phpmyadmin as it's own db, but have no clue where to put the site files nor how to point wp to the new db that I created.

help, please...???

Answer (score 1):

1. put your files to your file system on server as usual
2. create phpinfo file and put it to the same folder as your WP
3. find relative path (`$_ENV['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or `$_ENV['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`)
4. update relative path of web hosting everywhere in your SQL in `wp_options` (try to find e.g. `uninstall_plugins`)
5. in wp_options update also first two inputs

OR

just put this to your **wp-config.php** and everything else should be set automatically:

`define('WP_HOME','http://localhosturl.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhosturl.com');`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. while my problem remains unsolved, I'm one step closer.

I had to check the 'wp-config.php' file for the proper MySQL login credentials, and change the server ip.

however I'm still not able to get the site online on our LAN.

any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated! thanks again for your help!

Comment: do you have set define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); ?
are you getting any error messages?